# Rerun the whole test class using Spock, maven and surefire

Tags: maven, spock, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a bunch of tests implemented using Spock and that contain the @Stepwise clause, meaning that each test method contained in each class must be executed sequentially (they're dependant on the previous one).

Now I'd like to implement a retry mechanism for flaky tests and I'm trying the one provided by the surefire plugin.

this works, but it only retries the test method that failed, when I want it to rerun the whole class (even the tests that were executed correctly, since they're a pre-condition for the next ones). How can it be configured?

An example of how one of my test classes looks like (I know it's a stupid one, I just wrote it like this way because it is suitable as en example):

```
@Stepwise
class DummyTest extends loginWithNewUser {


def infoDialogAppears() {
    given:
    at homePage
    

    when:
    infoButton.click()      

    then:
    infoDialog

}

def closeInfoDialog() {
    when:
    infoDialog.close()

    then:
    !infoDialog
}
```

Comment: Feedback, please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your test is not a simple Spock test but a Geb test. Anyway, have you considered handling flaky tests with the Spock `@Retry` annotation available both in [Spock 1.3](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_retry) and [Spock 2.0](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0-M4/all_in_one.html#_retry)?

I have not tried to do that from Surefire/Failsafe or even tried to do it in Spock at all because I believe in fixing flaky tests and having them red if they do fail instead of hiding the flakiness, eliminating the desire to fix it. But FWIW, Spock has that feature built in and I recommend to use it sparingly and on a per-test basis rather than globally because re-running each single failing integration test (even the non-flaky ones) just makes your test execution slower and keeps developers waiting for feedback.

Comment: Well, I have actually changed the whole setup, in the end, to make the test methods independent among each other but still able to run stepwise. Using the Spock feature does not work for me as it requires quite a lot of manual effort in terms of maintenance

Comment: I had recommended to use it **sparingly,** then it is not a lot of maintenance effort. Furthermore, you would remove each annotation as soon as you refactored the corresponding test to not be flaky anymore. The annotation would also document which tests are flaky. It is worth the effort, except if most of your tests are flaky, which means there is something wrong with the tests. Don't use Surefire to just repeat the tests until they pass and hide the flakiness, but improve the tests. Otherwise they are pointless. Don't sweep the dirt under the rug, let failing tests hurt you.